# Ho do I ordering XMLArray Items of two different object list in alternate order?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have class Type which having Two list of different object types. When I am trying to serialize the Class Type I am getting list in sequence but I want to get the list of items in alternate order.

```
public class Type
{
    private List<Slow> slowField;

    private List<Fast> FastField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SLOW", Order=1)]
    public List<Slow> SLOW
    {
        get
        {
            return this.slowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.slowField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FAST", Order=2)]
    public List<Fast> FAST
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FastField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FastField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output :

```
<Type>
<SLOW>S1</SLOW>
<SLOW>S2</SLOW>
<SLOW>S3</SLOW>
<FAST>F1</FAST>
<FAST>F2</FAST>
<FAST>F3</FAST>
</Type>
```

I need this Output:

```
<Type>
<SLOW>S1</SLOW>
<FAST>F1</FAST>
<SLOW>S2</SLOW>
<FAST>F2</FAST>
<SLOW>S3</SLOW>
<FAST>F3</FAST>
</Type>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to introduce a third Collection which would combine the two existing collections in desired order. For example,

Assuming the structure of Fast and Slow are as follows

```
public class Fast
{
    public int Value{get;set;}
}

public class Slow
{
    public int Value{get;set;}
}
```

You could now introduce a Base Class (or use System.Object as common base) for both types. For example,

```
public class Base{}

public class Fast:Base
{
    public int Value{get;set;}
}

public class Slow:Base
{
    public int Value{get;set;}
}
```

Now you could add a third collection in your Type Class as following

```
[XmlElement("SLOW", Type = typeof(Slow))]
[XmlElement("FAST", Type = typeof(Fast))]
public List<Base> Complete => GetMergedList();

private List<Base> GetMergedList()
{
  int minLen = Math.Min(SLOW.Count, FAST.Count);

  var list = SLOW.Take(minLen)
            .Zip(FAST.Take(minLen), (a, b) => new Base[] { a, b })
            .SelectMany(array => array)
            .Concat(SLOW.Skip(minLen))
            .Concat(FAST.Skip(minLen));
  return list.ToList();
}
```

Note that the code assumes Fast and Slow collections are already sorted individually, but if not, need to add logic sorting them.

You would also need to mark the existing properties with `XmlIgnoreAttribute` to skip them during serialization.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<Slow> SLOW
{
....
}

[XmlIgnore]
public List<Fast> SLOW
{
....
}
```

Now you could serialize the Type instance to get the desired result.

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mjbDE1)

Answer (score 0):

Just alternate the output, if the iteration is odd print the first list if even print the second one. Do someting like this :

```
for( int i = 1; i < ListLength; i++) 
{
if( i%2 == 0)
{
// put here your second list dont forget to put i-1 since we started with 1 in for
print(" The value is even");
}
else 
{
//put here your first list
print("the value is odd");
}
}
```

Comment: But I am directly serialize the Type class. XMLSerializer is printing the data

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complex solution using IXmlSerialize. I don't know the details of the classes Fast and Slow.  So I'm just sorting the innertext of the xml element

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type test = new Type()
            {
                FAST = new List<Fast>() { new Fast() { value = "F1" }, new Fast() { value = "F2" }, new Fast() { value = "F3" } },
                SLOW = new List<Slow>() { new Slow() { value = "S1" }, new Slow() { value = "S2" }, new Slow() { value = "S3" } }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Type));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, test);

        }
    }
    public class Fast
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Slow
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type : IXmlSerializable
    {
        private List<Slow> slowField;
        private List<Fast> FastField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SLOW", Order = 1)]
        public List<Slow> SLOW
        {
            get
            {
                return this.slowField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.slowField = value;
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FAST", Order = 2)]
        public List<Fast> FAST
        {
            get
            {
                return this.FastField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.FastField = value;
            }
        }
        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'prefix'.*)(?'suffix'\d+)";

            XmlSerializer fastSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fast));
            XmlSerializer slowSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Slow));
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            settings.Indent = true;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter childWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms,settings);
            childWriter.WriteRaw("<Root>");
            foreach(Slow slow in slowField)
            {
                slowSerializer.Serialize(childWriter,slow);
                //childWriter.WriteRaw("\n");
            }
            foreach (Fast fast in FastField)
            {
                fastSerializer.Serialize(childWriter, fast);
                //childWriter.WriteRaw("\n");
            }
            childWriter.WriteRaw("</Root>");
            childWriter.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0; ;
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer()); 
            XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(ms);
            var orderChildren = rootElement.Elements()
                .Select(x => new { match = Regex.Match((string)x, pattern), element = x })
                .Select(x => new { prefix = x.match.Groups["prefix"].Value, suffix = x.match.Groups["suffix"].Value, element = x.element })
                .OrderBy(x => x.suffix)
                .ThenBy(x => x.prefix)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var orderChild in orderChildren)
            {
                orderChild.element.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XmlSerializer fastSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fast));
            XmlSerializer slowSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Slow));
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "SLOW")
                {
                    if (slowField == null) slowField = new List<Slow>();
                    slowField.Add((Slow)slowSerializer.Deserialize(reader));
                }
                if (reader.Name == "FAST")
                {
                    if (FastField == null) FastField = new List<Fast>();
                    FastField.Add((Fast)slowSerializer.Deserialize(reader));
                }
            }

        }
        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }
    }
}
```